# Debugging Coffeescript jasmine-node Tests in Webstorm/Intellij

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, coffeescript, jasmine-node

I'm using **node-jasmine 2 beta4** and writing in coffeescript. I'm happily running tests in Intellij 13.1 having setup the following Run Configuration

```
Node interpreter: /usr/local/bin/node 
Working Dir: [Project Directory]
Javascript File: node_modules/jasmine-node/bin/jasmine-node
Application Parameters: --coffee --verbose spec
```

I also have setup file watchers for all my coffeescript files and they are building correctly and put into a `[Project Directory]/.build` subdirectory

Great! But setting breakpoints when debugging is not working. The information sent back to Intellij seems to reference the javascript files given the line numbers I am seeing suggesting that sourcemaps are not being referenced correctly.

Can anyone help?

(Currently i make do by adding a `debugger` statement instead of intellij's breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

I think your Javascript file should be node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js. The [jasmine-node documentation](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) recommends using the cli.js file when using node directly instead of NPM (look under Usage).